# How to switch between two Angular applications

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot

I have one home page with a particular type of header and footer and a dashboard which has another header and footer. Both pages have been integrated in Angular JS 1.4. 
Now I'm stuck with how to switch between these two applications.

I'm not sure how to route to dashboard from my home page.

Comment: So they've both got separate pages, separate apps, separate routes etc? Also, are you using `java` at all or is that an incorrect tag?

Comment: They're both separate pages of one web app with separate routes. I am using spring boot as backend so kept tag Java

Comment: `how to switch between these two applications` you navigate using a url

Comment: Fair enough with the java tag, I was just checking :) Can you not just have a link from one page to another, without using the router in angular?